# Save all previous versions of a Word document as separate files at once

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a Word document saved in OneDrive that I've been editing for a couple of weeks. Autosave has built up a version history as I've made changes over time:

[image]

There are quite a lot of older versions of this document - I was wondering if there is a fast and efficient way to save them all as separate documents at once, as opposed to manually opening each one and saving them one at a time?

Comment: I do not know that OneDrive versions are in the Word object model: that is, accessible through vba. I've upvoted your question. There is nothing built into OneDrive to do this.